# No wifi on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, toshiba-satellite

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Toshiba Satellite L645D-S4030 laptop and I am unable to detect any wifi networks, my wifi light is not on, but I can still use an Ethernet connection. I know that our wifi is working since we are using it on other devices. I already tried fn f8 and it does not turn on the wifi. I am new to Ubuntu and Linux and I am sorry if I am missing something obvious. How do I get my computer to connect to my wifi network?

Edit: http://pastebin.com/MgD4pzsZ Wireless-info.txt

---

**EDITS FROM DISCUSSION BELOW**

1. `sudo rfkill unblock all` didn't work.
2. `lspci -v | grep -i wireless` Doesn't return any results.

From [@WildMan](https://askubuntu.com/users/153297/wild-man). It's a custom script written by him and friends that helps to diagnose wireless issues.

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script
```

The results of the script can be found at http://pastebin.com/MgD4pzsZ as above.

[@WildMan's](https://askubuntu.com/users/153297/wild-man) response:

> Your wifi is not showing up, it is an internal wifi correct? You may want to go into your bios and see if there is a setting to enable wifi if your bios is not UEFI then reset it and see if your wifi shows up. You can make sure it is plugged in good if none of those things help then your wifi card may be bad. Even if it was turned off or a driver was not installed you should be able to see if in the information you posted for me.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I bought a usb wireless adapter and now I have no issues with my wifi. I am guessing there was an issue with my wifi card, not ubuntu. I bought this one www.amazon.com/Panda-Ultra-aWireless-Adapter-150Mbps/dp/B00762YNMG/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1395928359&sr=1-2&keywords=ubuntu+wireless+adapter and just plugged it in and I have had no issues since.

Comment: Okay, that's nice. I wanted to start a bounty for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo rfkill unblock all` in terminal and trying again to reconnect.

Comment: I ran "sudo rfkill unblock all" in the terminal, and nothing has changed.I can't see any of the available wifi connections, or any options even related to the wifi. I am wondering if maybe I need a driver for my wifi card?

Comment: I need to know your wireless card model. Type `lspci -v | grep -i wireless` in the terminal and edit your question and include the result.

Comment: Sorry, but I just tried that and it didn't show anything. I just pasted it into the terminal and then pressed enter. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: What do you mean it didn't show anything? In my case, I got this output `02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)`

Comment: Wild Man, I added that txt file in the edit of my original post.

Comment: Avatar Parto, I paste it in, push enter, and then there is no output at all. It just goes back to the normal blank line in the terminal.

Comment: @user258943 That's strange. If you won't have got a solution in two days time (when the 'start a bounty' link becomes active), I'll start a bounty for you. Maybe other community members can be able to help.

Comment: Your wifi is not showing up, it is an internal wifi correct? You may want to go into your bios and see if there is a setting to enable wifi if your bios is not UEFI then reset it and see if your wifi shows up. You can make sure it is plugged in good if none of those things help then your wifi card may be bad. Even if it was turned off or a driver was not installed you should be able to see if in the information you posted for me.

Comment: To be fair, there are plenty of instructions in the comments. +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

### short answer:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

### explanation:

In `lsmod` you see the module "b43" gets loaded.

As you can see in `modinfo` this is a Broadcom chip and it requires firmware files. These are only available as BLOBs. That's why they are in a package with `-nonfree` in the name (in the "Multiverse" repository) and are not installed by default.

To find the package I simply picked one of the file names for the firmware and searched for package contents at [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Post the output from **`dmesg | grep -e b43 -e Broadcom -e 43xx`**; to show what is now happening (after loading **linux-firmware-nonfree** and restarting laptop).